# Is there any difference between add/access efficiency of stacks, queues and arrays?

Tags: arrays, performance, data-structures, stack, queue

FIFO vs. LIFO vs. access at any point is entirely irrelevant to me, as I plan to cycle through all the elements of whatever data structure I use and then add some of them to another data structure. For example, if I were using a stack, I would just push the data as it came in and the pop each element as I check it and add it to the new structure. If I used a queue, I would just queue/dequeue--it doesn't matter. Which structure is most efficient for this?

Comment: I'd say the language you're planning to use is a factor aswell since not every language handles the above mentioned structures the same. Generally speaking I'd say stack > array > list.